# Configuring Dispatcher for akka logging

Tags: java, scala, akka

I dug into akka's sources and figured out that it uses the so called `BusLogging` class which publishes messages to `EventStream`. `EventStream::publish(event: Event)` in turns just publishes the event to the receivers which are in `cache: Map.empty[Classifier, Set[Subscriber]]`.

I found that logging is being performed by the `/system/log1-Slf4jLogger` actor. The [***documentation***](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/logging.html#Loggers) says:

> ***The event handler actor*** does not have a bounded inbox and ***is run on***
>   ***the default dispatcher***. This means that logging extreme amounts of
>   data may affect your application badly. It can be somewhat mitigated
>   by making sure to use an async logging backend though.

Is there a way to move it to another dispatcher which I configure the way I want?

Answer (score 2):

You may configure it by adding these params into your `application.conf` file:

```
akka.loggers-dispatcher = "my-blocking-dispatcher"

my-blocking-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 4
  }
  throughput = 1
}
```

Akka config reference:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/dispatchers.html
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/general/configuration.html#config-akka-remote